# mysql insert query in a php script is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that take data from a table and then try to insert the obtained data in a second table copy of the first one:

```
function copy_data($id,$mysql_conn){
 if($res=mysql_query("SELECT * from table1 WHERE id='".$id."'", $mysql_conn)){
       if($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            $sql  ="INSERT INTO table2 (id, Field1, Field2) values('" . $row['id'] . "', '" . $row['Field1'] . "', '" . $row['Field2'] . "')";
            mysql_query($sql,$mysql_conn);
           }
}
}   
copy_data($id,$mysql_conn);// $id is id of the element I want to add
```

The insert query works fine but there is one case that makes an exception :one of the field contains a ' character, exp of a query that failed:
INSERT INTO table2 (id, Field1, Field2) values ('12','Company', 'Kurt's Reifen-Shop') the exception comes from the ' character how to insert php variables that do contain this character.

Comment: http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: The MySQL family of PHP is deprecated and support thereof will disappear. Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). All answers currently fail to mention that!

Comment: addslashes() function worked for me

Comment: @Amani **NO**. `addslashes` does not fix anything. Please, no.

Comment: @tadman but why ?I am not welling to update my php and mysql versions right now.

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. If you keep writing code like this, you will get into serious trouble. Re-writing it in PDO might be annoying, but it'll go a long way towards not having your site compromised.

Comment: It's not about your willingness to update your php and mysql. Either update or regret it when someone broke into your servers and databases, stole information or damaged it beyond any repair.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the data before insert them into $sql:

```
function copy_data($id,$mysql_conn){
 if($res=mssql_query("SELECT * from table1 WHERE id='".$id."'", $mysql_conn)){
       if($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            $row['Field1'] = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Field1']);
            $row['Field2'] = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Field2']);
            $sql  ="INSERT INTO table2 (id, Field1, Field2) values('" . $row['id'] . "', '" . $row['Field1'] . "', '" . $row['Field2'] . "')";
            mysql_query($sql,$mysql_conn);
           }
}
}   
copy_data($id,$mysql_conn);// $id is id of the element I want to add
```

Comment: "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future." From PHP.net, Better to use PDO that provide the prepared query witch is way better secured than using mysql_real_escape_string() !

Comment: It's also obnoxious to have to write SQL code like this. PDO is ten times easier to write and even easier to read to check that you've done it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single statement:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
INSERT INTO table2 (id, Field1, Field2) SELECT id, Field1, Field2 FROM table1 WHERE id='".$id."'"
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand how you managed to put that ' in to the first table but you should use 
mysql_real_escape_string
like $field1 = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Field1']);
than put the $field1 as it will be safe now